# How to synchronize breakpoints between 2 visual studios?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am buildling a network application, so I can run 2 instances of my application. To debug it I attach one visual studio (2010) to each instance. I would like to sync my breakpoints so when I add one it is added on both VS. Is it possible ?

Comment: No, nothing in the box for that.  Nor does it make much sense, I'd guess you'll want to debug the transmitting code in one, the receiving code in the other.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual studio 2017 it is possible to export your list of breakpoints by clicking on "Export all breakpoints matching the current search criteria".
[visual studio export breakpoints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdVN9.png)